# Google Sheet Sparkline Progress bar

Tags: google-sheets

I'm building a Delivery Schedule which pulls data from another sheet.

The Delivery schedule should have a quick colour coded points of reference. To do this I'm looking at having a Sparkline as a progress bar.

I'd like the sparkline  (In column D) to start Red, The target volume is in Column B, Assigned Volumes are in Column F & as the volume in Column F gets closer to the target volume in Column B, the sparkline changes colour to Green. Once the target volume has been achieved, The status in Column E will be changed to "Closed" and the sparkline will then change to Grey.

I've discovered I'm useless at finding the formula to achieve this.

Image below is an example of what i'm working with
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below formula in cell **C8**:

```
=ifs(D8="Closed",Sparkline(E8,{"charttype","bar";"color1","gray";"Max",B8}),(E8/B8)<=0.8,Sparkline(E8,{"charttype","bar";"color1","red";"Max",B8}),(E8/B8)>0.8,Sparkline(E8,{"charttype","bar";"color1","green";"Max",B8}))
```

> Closer value kept at **80%** change the value in the formula as per your
> need

And for the status **column E** try below:

```
   =if((E8/B8)>=1,"Closed","Open")
```

> Closed status value kept at 100% change the value in the formula as
> per your need

[image]

Comment: Perfect, works a treat. Thanks very much!